# git add unchanged files into "unstaged files"

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

git is adding unchanged files into "unstaged files"

[image]

As you can see, these files are added into the "**Unstaged files**" section, but when I click on them, **no changes are made**.

What is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: They are in the `out` directory, shouldn't that be ignored entirely?

Comment: So should I manually ignore all files from the ```out``` directory?
Sorry if it's obvious, i'm new ^^

Comment: Or just the whole directory, `out/`. See e.g. https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/b5aa92c05f3659fcb5910836199ce836291158be/Global/JetBrains.gitignore#L47

Comment: okay I understand, but do I have to create this .gitignore file manually (new text file) or there is a more conventional way?

Comment: What? Creating a `.gitignore` file *is* the conventional way. It's how you tell git what files and directories you don't want it to track.

Comment: Just download a gitignore from https://gitignore.io and select things like `intellij+all`. But keep in mind that you should delete the out folder on git(`git rm -r --cached out`) before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's compiled classes, as mention before they must be ignored.
In root folder of project create `.gitignore` file and add there rows

```
out/
.idea/
```

---

No changes are made because you didn't start to tracking them, so basically all file is "one big change"